# How to translate the SCOM Notification Subscription ID to the Subscription Name

Tags: scom, subscription

In SCOM notifications, the last line reads

> Notification subscription ID generating this message: {DFF2B469-4D4D-3F82-C51B-FCAC7A863DE6}

I want to convert the GUID to the Subscription Name.  I've searched and found references to using

```
Get-NotificationSubscription -id DFF2B469-4D4D-3F82-C51B-FCAC7A863DE6 | ft Display
```

But I'm just getting either the error

> 'Get-NotificationSubscription' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

from the command prompt, or

> Get-NotificationSubscription : The term 'Get-NotificationSubscription'
>   is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

from PowerShell.

Haven't figured out what I might be doing wrong yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems:

1. The command apparently *changed* from SCOM2007 to SCOM2012, and is now Get-**SCOM**NotificationSubscription, and Display has changed to DisplayName
2. The command can **not** be run from the command prompt **or** PowerShell.  SCOM has its own "Operations Manager Shell" that must be used to access the command.  To get to the shell:

   - Go to All Programs -> Microsoft System Center 2012 -> Operation Manager
   - Click on **Operations Manager Shell**.
   - Then you can run the command

     `Get-SCOMNotificationSubscription -id <GUID> | ft DisplayName`